# How to override back button for a page outside of it?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know how to override back button inside a page:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   //Do your work here
   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

**But the problem:** I use `Inneractive` ad service. when I call `InneractiveAd.DisplayAd()` it shows a new page of its own which doesn't support back button. when it navigate to this page its uri is like this:

```
/Inneractive.Ad;component/InneractiveFullScreenPage.xaml
```

**The question:** is it possible to override back button of that page to navigate back when user presses back?

Comment: If I understood you cerrectly that you want to override OnBackKeyPress of the Page that InneractiveAd.DisplayAd() navigates and it is a Page somewhere in Inneractive.Ad (which you don't have source code), and you cannot redirect the Navigation - then it can be hard to achieve (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HandleBackKeyPress you usually intercept BackKeyPress event, so you would set `e.Cancel = true` to prevent *standard* BackKey navigation. To simulate standard navigation you would do something like:

```
void HookUpBackKeyPress(PhoneApplicationPage page)
{
    page.BackKeyPress += HandleBackKeyPress;
}

void HandleBackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    page.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

The problem is to get the reference to the navigated page. The following code will work only after you completely Navigated to the new Page and it might not work when immediately after `NavigationService.Navigate(..)`

```
var frame = (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual;
page = (PhoneApplicationPage)frame.Content;
```